# I want the menu left of the iframe

Tags: html, css, alignment

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1u8T.png)

Don't know how i can put the link menu left of the iframe

I want the menu left of the iframe

the iframe is the gallery slide show

```
                       <div class="btn-group">
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='vrijwerk/demo/basic.htm';">Vrijwerk</button>
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='hoeden/demo/basic.htm';">Hoeden</button>
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='vrijwerk/demo/basic.htm';">Vrijwerk</button>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                                    <iframe class="iframe" name="iframe" align="right" height="800" width="90%" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" src="vrijwerk/demo/basic.htm"></iframe>
                                    
                    </div>
```

Comment: start using bootstrap.

Comment: @user2631588 plz dont forget to accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap  them in a div and use flex

```css
.wrapper{display:flex;}
.btn-group{display:flex;
flex-direction:column;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  <div class="btn-group">
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='vrijwerk/demo/basic.htm';">Vrijwerk</button>
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='hoeden/demo/basic.htm';">Hoeden</button>
                        
                        <button target="iframe" onclick="iframe.location.href='vrijwerk/demo/basic.htm';">Vrijwerk</button>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                                    <iframe class="iframe" name="iframe" align="right" height="800" width="90%" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"></iframe>
                                    
                    </div>     </div>
```